# how to find results in mysql within the specfied times range?

Tags: sql, mysql

My table

> **ID StartTime EndTime**

1    09:00:00   10:00:00

2    10:30:00   11:00:00

3    14:30:00   16:00:00

How to check the if passed date ranges fall in between the Start and End Times...like when i say, if starttime is **09:24:00** and endtime is **09:56:00**? it should return Id value of 1

Can you some please help me with this?

Comment: What are the types of StartTime and EndTime columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) if a value is `between` two other values. Note that BETWEEN comparison includes the borders.

```
WHERE `time` BETWEEN `StartTime` AND `EndTime`
```

Of course don't forget to

```
CAST(`time` AS TIME)
```

if it it isn't of the type `TIME`.

---

To check for a range:

```
WHERE 
    (CAST(`rangeStart` AS TIME) BETWEEN `StartTime` AND `EndTime`) AND 
    (CAST(`rangeEnd` AS TIME) BETWEEN `StartTime` AND `EndTime`)
```

Comment: but i need to pass 2 times here (starttime and endtime)

Comment: See the edit for checking a range. Also: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Where StartTime < time and EndTime > time

Answer (score 0):

Ttry out following query

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
 WHERE StartTime < cast('09:24:00' as time) 
 AND   EndTime > cast('09:56:00' as time);
```