# date time compare in mysql and php for booking meeting

Tags: php, mysql

i need to book meeting room
start date and end date are of date+time type in mysql
when ever user enters data, values get stored in these format 2013-10-03 14:30:00 to 2013-10-03 16:30:00 (both start and end date) and along with that room number(example:2) is also stored.

now suppose user has made a new entry again, with

```
1)same time and and same booking room ( start_date : 2013-10-03 14:30:00 to end_date: 2013-10-03 16:30:00)
2)different time and same booking room (start_date:2013-10-03 13:30:00 to end_date: 2013-10-03 15:30:00)
3)different time and same booking room (start_date:2013-10-03 15:30:00 to end_date: 2013-10-03 18:30:00)
```

in all above case, it should so me error saying this time is not available as its already booked.

what i have done till now is  :

```
SELECT  * FROM    calendar WHERE `Room_no`='2' and (StartTime BETWEEN $start_date AND '$start_date' OR EndTime BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date)
```

Thanks in advance.i am new to php and mysql.so if any mistake i have done please let me know.

Comment: Are there any errors?  What is the problem?

Comment: I cant understand your problem. Do you want that at one time, only one person can book a room? Is that all what you want? If yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163092/how-to-find-results-in-mysql-within-the-specfied-times-range?rq=1#answer-4163132

Comment: this i tried but uts nt showing poper answer.YES bhavik, i want if that room is booked at that particular time, it should not allow to book that room.

Comment: If start time and end time are DateTime are you formating them correctly? like `->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: yes.its same format ('Y-m-d H:i:s').

Comment: Remember. Time is linear. In consequence, I suspect you're only interested in those instances where $start_date < EndTime AND $end_date > StartTime

Answer (score 0):

At first it's very difficult to know what your exact problem is.

Look at the query below. You are using between query between same variable names $start_date and '$start_date'.

SELECT  * FROM    calendar 
WHERE `Room_no`='2'
AND (StartTime BETWEEN **$start_date AND '$start_date'**) 
OR (EndTime BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date)

I think you have wrong sql.

Comment: sorry for posting wrong query...it is $start_date and $end_date

Comment: in my answer i have not post the query that works. i've just show where is the mistake in query. please read the answer first before comment.